# Can silverlight wcf service calls be cache?

Tags: ajax, silverlight, web-services

This is a wcf binaryencoding service that the application is calling.  It takes 3 parameters.

I know you could do this is javascript ajax stacks, but I never tried it with Silverlight.  Is this possible because I am making the same long running web service call 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you cache on the server side? Certainly, and depending on the nature of the actual service, you may get a lot of it "for free" using the web caching mechanisms.

Can you cache on the Silverlight side? Certainly, and if you have to make the call numerous times for the same data, grabbing it once and saving it client side makes more sense than calling the service numerous times, even if you can set up caching on the service side.